# Multi-Monitor with multiple computers

Tags: multiple-monitors, window-manager

I need to know if there's an free application that does the same as the MaxiVista "Extended Screen" functionality.

Basically is to use a 2nd computer screen as an extra monitor of the main machine.
http://www.maxivista.com/multi_monitor.htm

This is different from Synergy or Input Director that "only" able to manage multiple computer with a single mouse/keyboard.

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 1):

on windows I use VNC, on X I use x2x, on mixed bags x2vnc.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically is to use a 2nd computer
>   screen as an extra monitor of the main
>   machine.

**[ZoneScreen](http://www.zoneos.com/zonescreen.htm)** does exactly that.

[image]

ZoneScreen works only up to Windows XP. Although there are workarounds for Windows Vista/7 i can't vouch for that.

*ZoneScreen is freeware.*

Answer (score 1):

Thaks guys, I ended buying MaxiVista.

My current configuration is a desktop PC with 2 monitors attached (22" and 19") and a Laptop.
The Laptop screen is pretty much useless... I have mail and secondary stuff going on there but I feel the need of a 3rd monitor on me daily work.

With MaxiVista I'm able to drag the windows of the desktop PC to the Laptop monitor like if it was a ordinary monitor attached to a graphic card on my PC.

It also gives me the ability to switch between Extended Screen and Remote Control modes.
On Remote Control mode MaxiVista acts like Synergy or Input Director.

Cheers,
Alex