# ubuntu Multi-Monitor with multiple computers (monitor sharing)

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, window-manager, synergy

I want to use 4 monitors but the videocards have outpus only for 2 video cards.

is there a way to work on one computer but use the monitor of another computer as an extension of the windows space.

kind of like synergy but in addition i want to share the window manager so that all programs lunch on the original computer. the second computer is old and not as powerful.

Comment: this post is similar but it's for windows http://superuser.com/questions/94448/multi-monitor-with-multiple-computers

Comment: I realize that i can just use synergy and "ssh -X" but i would also like to be able to bring a window over to another machine

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Xdmx](http://dmx.sourceforge.net/).

> Say you are running `Xdmx` on a machine called `x0` and you have two other machines available,
>   `x1` and `x2`, both of which have X servers running on them (i.e., you have logged into the
>   console on `x1` and `x2` and are running an X session). To start `Xdmx`, use the following command:
>
> ```
> Xdmx :1 +xinerama -display x1:0 -display x2:0
> ```
>
> There should now be an X server running on `x0` with the `DISPLAY` name `":1"` (or, `"x0:1"`). The
>   displays on `x1` and `x2` provide a unified input display, and the mouse on `x1` should be able
>   to move the cursor from `x1` to `x2` and back again. You can now set up applications to run
>   on `":1"`, with the output being displayed on the `x1` and `x2` displays.

To include the local display, prepend another `-display` option naming the local display device (that is, `:0`).

Comment: Hi, looks like what i was looking for. but i get an error:"(Fatal Error) dmx: dmxOpenDisplay: Unable to open display dhcp-187-122.chem.rochester.edu:0"

Comment: i also followed this http://www.yolinux.com/HOWTO/Remote-X-Apps.html#s9 and tried: "xfig -display dhcp-187-122.chem.rochester.edu:0" and got an error Error: Can't open display: dhcp-187-122.chem.rochester.edu:0 .  ssh -X works fine though